# Plotting Pandas DataFrames as single days on the x-axis in Python/Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I've got data like this:

```
    col1  ;col2
2001-01-01;1
2001-01-01;2
2001-01-02;3
2001-01-03;4
2001-01-03;2
2001-01-04;2
```

I'm reading it in Python/Pandas using `pd.read_csv(...)` into a DataFrame.
Now I want to plot col2 on the y-axis and col1 on the x-axis day-wise. I searched a lot but couldn't too many very useful pages describing this in detail. I found that matplotlib does currently NOT support the dataformat in which the dates are stored in (datetime64).

I tried converting it like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
X = np.asarray(df['col1']).astype(DT.datetime)
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b %d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax.plot(X, df['col2'])
plt.show()
```

but this does NOT work.
What is the best way? 
I can only find bits there and bits there, but nothing really working in complete and more importantly, up-to-date ressources related to this functionality for the latest version of pandas/numpy/matplotlib.

I'd also be interested to convert this absolut dates to consecutive day-indices, i.e:
The starting day *2001-01-01* is Day **1**, thus the data would look like this:

```
    col1  ;col2 ; col3
2001-01-01;1;1
2001-01-01;2;1
2001-01-02;3;2
2001-01-03;4;3
2001-01-03;2;3
2001-01-04;2;4
.....
2001-02-01;2;32
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as far as I can see there's no need anymore to use `matplotlib` directly, but instead pandas itself already offer plotting functions which can be used as methods to the dataframe-objects, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html. These functions themselves use matplotlib, but are easier to use because they handle the datatypes correctly themselves :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pandas.read_csv supports parse_dates=True (default of course is False) That would save you converting the dates separately.

Also for a simple dataframe like this, pandas plot() function works perfectly well.
Example:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20160601',periods=4)
dt = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,1),index=dates,columns=['col1'])
dt.plot()
plt.show()
```